# How do I web scrape using links contained in a text file?

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to create a powershell script that pulls CVE numbers from a website. The website links are specified in a text file and look like this:

```
Application   : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
Creator       : 1480803660     Parent        : System.__ComObject
Name          : https://www.cisa.gov/uscert/ics/advisories/icsa-22-006-01
Range         : System.__ComObject
Shape         : 
SubAddress    : 
Address       : https://www.cisa.gov/uscert/ics/advisories/icsa-22-006-01
```

The code I currently have is running into an error about"null-value expressions", and I cannot seem to get the code to work. I suspect it might be a problem with the way I'm attempting to read the text file.

```
$Path = "C:\Users\Windows\Downloads\Links.txt"
$values = Get-Content $Path | Where-Object {$_ -like '*Name*'}
$URI = $values

ForEach ($URI in $Path){
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI -UseBasicParsing
($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("a") | Where{ $_.href -eq 'http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId' } ).innerText | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Users\Windows\Downloads\CVEList'
}
```

Comment: Don't use `-UseBasicParsing;`. If you do, you loose the `ParsedHtml` bit of the line after.
Also, the parsing itself is gone from PS 6.0+ (It is always basic parsing in later versio).

Comment: The whole bit about values, URI and foreach URI in Path doesn't quite make sense to me. Maybe I'm just too tired today but I'm basically reading this as `for each <entire collection> in <file where I got the collection> { do something }`

Comment: @notjustme Yes that's correct mostly. I'm trying to do something like: for each <website link> in <file where the collection is> {do xyz}.

Comment: @soccerrat `foreach($item in $URI) { <do stuff> -Uri $item }` would make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement the the comment from [**@Sage**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934946/sage-pourpre) with a possible workaround for newer PowerShell versions using the [HTMLDocument Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/edotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) from Microsoft Windows:

```
function ParseHtml($String) {
    $Unicode = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($String)
    $Html = New-Object -Com 'HTMLFile'
    if ($Html.PSObject.Methods.Name -Contains 'IHTMLDocument2_Write') {
        $Html.IHTMLDocument2_Write($Unicode)
    } 
    else {
        $Html.write($Unicode)
    }
    $Html.Close()
    $Html
}

$Uri = 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/72720158/1701026'
$Html = ParseHtml (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI).Content
$Html.body.getElementsByTagName('a') |ForEach-Object { $_.href }
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Invoke-WebRequest doesn't seem to work in newer Powershell, as it says "The 'file' scheme is not supported". Seems I'll have to find another way to access the DOM.

Comment: @soccerrat, it should also work with newer PowerShell versions. I don't know what exactly is in your `Links.txt`. Therefore I have changed the answer with a more general example (that just pulls all the `href`s from all the `a`nchors on this specific stackoverflow issue to prove that it works.