# Extract URLs from webpages

Tags: html, powershell, uri

I want to extract URLs from a webpage that contains multiple URLs in it and save the extracted to a txt file.

The URLs in the webpage starts '127.0.0.1' but i wanted to remove  '127.0.0.1' from them and extract only the URLs. When i run the ps script below, it only saves '127.0.0.1'. Any help to fix this please.

```
$threatFeedUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DandelionSprout/adfilt/master/Alternate versions Anti-Malware List/AntiMalwareHosts.txt"
    
    # Download the threat feed data
    $threatFeedData = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $threatFeedUrl
    
    # Define a regular expression pattern to match URLs starting with '127.0.0.1'
    $pattern = '127\.0\.0\.1(?:[^\s]*)'
    
    # Use the regular expression to find matches in the threat feed data
    $matches = [regex]::Matches($threatFeedData.Content, $pattern)
    
    # Create a list to store the matched URLs
    $urlList = @()
    
    # Populate the list with matched URLs
    foreach ($match in $matches) {
        $urlList += $match.Value
    }
    
    # Specify the output file path
    $outputFilePath = "output.txt"
    
    # Save the URLs to the output file
    $urlList | Out-File -FilePath $outputFilePath
    
    Write-Host "URLs starting with '127.0.0.1' extracted from threat feed have been saved to $outputFilePath."
```

Comment: Be careful out there. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/447901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**:

- The target URL happens to be a (semi-structured) *plain-text* resource, so [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based processing *is* appropriate.
- In general, however, with *HTML* content, using a dedicated parser is preferable, given that regexes aren't capable of parsing HTML *robustly*.<sup>[1]</sup> See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72720158/45375) for an example of extracting links from an HTML document.

---

> ```bash
> '127\.0\.0\.1(?:[^\s]*)'
> ```

- You're mistakenly using a *non-capturing* group (`(?:…)`) rather than a *capturing* one (`(…)`)
- In the downloaded content, there is a *space* after `127.0.0.1`
- Therefore use the following regex instead (`\S` is the simpler equivalent of `[^\s]` `+` only matches only a *non-empty* run of non-whitespace characters):

  ```bash
  '127\.0\.0\.1 (\S+)'
  ```

> ```bash
> $matches = …
> ```

- While it technically doesn't cause a problem here, `$matches` is the name of the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches), and therefore shouldn't be used for custom purposes.

> ```bash
> $match.Value
> ```

- `$match.Value` is the *whole* text that your regex matched, whereas you only want the text of the *capture group*.
- Use `$match.Groups[1].Value` instead.

> ```bash
> $urlList +=
> ```

- Building an array *iteratively*, with `+=` is *inefficient*, because a *new* array must be allocated behind the scenes in every iteration; simply use the `foreach` statement *as an expression*, and let PowerShell collect the results for you. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375) for more information.

> ```bash
> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $threatFeedUrl
> ```

- Since you're only interested in the *text content* of the response, it is simpler to use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) rather than [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest); the former returns the content *directly* (no need to access a `.Content` property).

To put it all together:

```bash
$threatFeedUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DandelionSprout/adfilt/master/Alternate versions Anti-Malware List/AntiMalwareHosts.txt'
    
# Download the threat feed data
$threatFeedData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $threatFeedUrl
    
# Define a regular expression pattern to match URLs starting with '127.0.0.1'
$pattern = '127\.0\.0\.1 (\S+)'
    
# Use the regular expression to find matches in the threat feed data
$matchList = [regex]::Matches($threatFeedData, $pattern)
    
# Create and populate the list with matched URLs
$urlList = 
  foreach ($match in $matchList) {
    $match.Groups[1].Value
  }
    
# Specify the output file path
$outputFilePath = 'output.txt'
    
# Save the URLs to the output file
$urlList | Out-File -FilePath $outputFilePath
    
Write-Host "URLs starting with '127.0.0.1' extracted from threat feed have been saved to $outputFilePath."
```

---

<sup>[1] See [this blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) for background information.</sup>